# Whats the appropriate condition to end my for loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I need to add the following intervals to the for loop (I tried with if statements and the teacher asked me to reduce the amount of coding).

```
Intervals (Pizza Diameters)   
12 - 20 = 8 slices  
21 - 24 = 12 slices   
25 - 30 = 16 slices  
31 - 36 = 24 slices
```

The following code gives me output that's pretty close to what I need, except that it doesn't adhere to the conditions above. For example if I enter 24 it should only give me the output for 8 and 12 slices.

```
int[] pizzaSlices = new int[4] { 8, 12, 16, 24 };

for (int i = pizzaSlices[0]; i < inputDiameter; i++) {
    if (i == pizzaSlices[0] || i == pizzaSlices[1] || i == pizzaSlices[2] ||
        i == pizzaSlices[3]) {

       Console.WriteLine("cut in " + i + " slices results in a slice area of " +
       Math.Round(areaOfThePizza / i, 2) + " per slices");

    }
}
```

Current Output:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: What output do you want, what output are you receiving and what other relevant code are you leaving out?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/218bb093143b926ae765e8869f299c06 this is the output im currently getting by typing 25, I want that same output but following the intervals I posted.

Comment: Just spent 20 minutes fiddling in Excel trying to find a correlation between pizza diameters and number of slices. Nothing. Your teacher is evil.

Comment: yes the actual Assignment was different because it had a 20 between 16 and 24, he removed it on purpose so we couldn't just add by 4. ^^

Comment: @JonnyHenly Yeah, I got that. I was approaching the problem from another angle and was trying to derive a formula that, given pizza diameter, would produce the desired number of slices.

Comment: so I would have to use if statements no matter what right?

Comment: As far as I can tell you have to use an if statement. I think your teacher wants you to incorporate a for loop instead of only using if statements. They're probably trying to teach you how to use a for loop and what its benefits are.

Comment: yea thanks for the help guys I would try to redo my old code with a for loop and try to make it shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added another `int` array to hold the pizza diameters. The `for` loop iterates from `0` to the length of `pizzaSlices`, so `0` to `3`.

The `if` statement in the `for` loop checks if the user entered diameter is in the range of the current iteration's `pizzaDims` counterpart.

```
int[] pizzaSlices = new int[4] { 8, 12, 16, 24 };
int[] pizzaDims = new int[4] { 12, 21, 25, 31 }; // pizza diameters array

if(inputDiameter >= smallest) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= pizzaSlices.Length; i++) {
        if(inputDiameter >= pizzaDims[i] {
            Console.WriteLine("cut in " + pizzaSlices[i] + 
                              " slices results in a slice area of " +
                              Math.Round(areaOfThePizza / pizzaSlices[i], 2) +
                              " per slices");
        } else {
            break; // no need to continue iterating, if one condition is false then
                   // the rest will be as well
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is giving me somewhat of a logic error after I enter the diameter, but it shows the output which is correct but if the input is divisible by 16 slices, it should also show the option to divide it by 12 and 8.

Comment: @BrianNaranjo no problem, let me know if you need additional help.

Comment: I was still getting a logic error but by I adding 12 to the diameter array it fixed it except for the number 36 seems to be the only1 with this problem.

Comment: Oh wow I fixed one logical error and introduced another, I'll fix it.

Comment: It should work now, I replaced the maximums with the minimums in  `pizzaDims`. I also added that `else` with a `break` but it's not necessary. It is more efficient though. Let me know if this isn't correct either.

Comment: haha now I get the original logic error we first had but is okay, for the previous version of this code I switched diam max to 37 instead of 36 and it now works with 36, ill fix it eventually still got a few more days for this. thanks a lot for the help tho

Comment: since 37 is out of the 12 -36 range it goes straight to the error message so it doesn't even gives a logic error anymore

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't resist adding a somewhat LINQ'y solution:

```
[Test]
[TestCase(37, Result = 0)]
[TestCase(36, Result = 24)]
[TestCase(35, Result = 24)]
[TestCase(30, Result = 16)]
[TestCase(29, Result = 16)]
[TestCase(26, Result = 16)]
[TestCase(22, Result = 12)]
[TestCase(12, Result = 8)]
[TestCase(11, Result = 0)]
[TestCase(10, Result = 0)]
public int GetNumberOfSlices(int diameter)
{
    var pizzas = new[] {
        new[] { 11, 0 }, 
        new[] { 20, 8 }, 
        new[] { 24, 12 }, 
        new[] { 30, 16 }, 
        new[] { 36, 24 }
    };
    var pizza = pizzas.FirstOrDefault(p => diameter <= p[0]);

    return pizza == null ? 0 : pizza[1];
}
```